# Como juntar vários datas frames em um só

Tags: r, data.frame

Quero criar um data frame como junção de 4 outros data frames. Consegui fazer isso usando tais comandos:

```r
ZHO<-as.data.frame.matrix(zho)
ZHO
ZES<-as.data.frame.matrix(zes)
ZES
ZRE<-as.data.frame.matrix(zre)
ZRE
POP<-as.data.frame.matrix(pop)
POP

dataframe1<-merge(ZHO,ZES)
dataframe1

dataframe1<-merge(dataframe1,ZRE)
dataframe1
dataframe1<- merge(dataframe1,POP)
dataframe1
```

Porém gostaria de saber se há outro jeito, pois esse jeito é trabalhoso e não funciona quando eu tenho uma quantidade muito grande datas frames

Answer (score 3):

Para ilustrar, vou criar 3 data.frames diferentes de exemplo, um com a variável `x`, outro com variável `y` e outro com a variável `z` para os mesmos indivíduos `id`:

```r
### exemplos ####
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, y = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(id=1:10, x = rnorm(10))
```

Com as funções base do R, uma forma de fazer um merge direto dos três é combinando a função `Reduce` com o `merge`:

```r
resultado <- Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, list(df1, df2, df3))
resultado
   id          y           z           x
1   1 -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
2   2  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
3   3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
4   4  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
5   5  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
6   6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
7   7  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
8   8  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
9   9  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
10 10 -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156
```

No pacote [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html), existe a função `join_all`, que faz basicamente o mesmo que foi feito acima, mas com uma sintaxe mais simples:

```r
library(plyr) ### se você ainda não tem o pacote, você tem que instalar antes

resultados <- join_all(list(df1,df2,df3)) 
resultados

   id          y           z           x
1   1 -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
2   2  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
3   3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
4   4  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
5   5  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
6   6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
7   7  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
8   8  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
9   9  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
10 10 -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156
```

Ou se você só quer digitar de uma maneira mais limpa, você pode usar o pacote [`magrittr` que tem um forward pipe operator para o R.](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) Com este pacote, o `merge` dos 3 data.frames também pode ser feito em uma linha só encadeando os argumentos com o operador `%>%`:

```r
 library(magrittr) ### se você ainda não tem o pacote, você tem que instalar antes

 resultado <- df1%>%merge(df2)%>%merge(df3)
 resultado

   id          y           z           x
1   1 -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
2   2  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
3   3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
4   4  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
5   5  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
6   6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
7   7  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
8   8  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
9   9  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
10 10 -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156
```

Lembrando que é sempre bom você especificar quais são as colunas identificadoras do `merge` (opção `by` da função), pois do contrário você pode acabar tendo como resultado final algo diferente do esperado. No caso acima isso não é necessário porque temos apenas uma coluna em comum.

Answer (score 1):

Com o `dplyr` você pode usar as funções de join encadeadas com o piper operator `%>%` (`inner_join`, `full_join`, `left_join`, `right_join` etc, dependendo do seu objetivo).

Exemplo com `full_join` encadeado:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, y = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(id=1:10, x = rnorm(10))

df1 %>% full_join(df2) %>% full_join(df3)

  id          y           z           x
1   1 -0.6264538  1.51178117  0.91897737
2   2  0.1836433  0.38984324  0.78213630
3   3 -0.8356286 -0.62124058  0.07456498
4   4  1.5952808 -2.21469989 -1.98935170
5   5  0.3295078  1.12493092  0.61982575
6   6 -0.8204684 -0.04493361 -0.05612874
7   7  0.4874291 -0.01619026 -0.15579551
8   8  0.7383247  0.94383621 -1.47075238
9   9  0.5757814  0.82122120 -0.47815006
10 10 -0.3053884  0.59390132  0.41794156
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quem quer uma alternativa "nova".

Tem as funções:

```
bind_rows(..., .id = NULL)

bind_cols(...)

combine(...)
```

**Elas estão no pacote `dplyr`** que vale muito a pena de ser estudados.

Comment: André, essas funções não são para fazer merge de data.frames.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Load Spreadsheet, separator "," (Planilha sepada por vígula)
obs_1 <- read.csv("constituents-financials-observations-1.csv")

head(obs_1) ## Visualizing data frame obs_1

obs_2 <- read.csv("constituents-financials-observations-2.csv")

head(obs_2) ## Visualizing data frame obs_2

## both dataframe have the same structure - column number = 12 

newCols = 12 

## new variables for both dataframes will be price_1,price_2,...
newNames = paste("price", seq_len(newCols), sep = "_") 

## set new names of the columns (price_1, price_2,...)

## Data frame obs_1
colnames(obs_1) <- newNames 

## change the name of the last variable
colnames(obs_1)[12] <- 'Síte' 

## change the name of firt variable
colnames(obs_1)[1] <- 'Sign'  

## Data frame obs_2
colnames(obs_2) <- newNames

colnames(obs_2)[12] <- 'Site'

colnames(obs_2)[1] <- 'Sign'

## full join in both dataframe. merge = lines of obs_1 + lines of obs_2
observations <- merge(obs_1, obs_2, all = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `cbind` que é do pacote base da linguagem R:

Utilizando o data frame criado pelo Carlos Cinelli:

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, y = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:10, z = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(id=1:10, x = rnorm(10))
```

```
df4 <- cbind(df1,df2,df3)
```

cbind faz a junção dos data.frames pela **coluna**

rbind faz a junção dos data.frames pela **linha**

Só que neste exemplo as colunas iguais não serão removidas e nem fundidas.