# Como atualizar coluna de um dataframe no R utilizando joins sem precisar criar outro objeto?

Tags: sql, r

Rapazeada blz?

Cara sou newbie no R e gostaria de saber se é possivel atualizar um data.frame no R fazendo chave com outro data.frame, a analogia em tsql seria essa:

Update a
Set a.col1 = b.col2
From tb1 a
Join tb2 b
On a.chave1 = b.chave2

Existe alguma funçao que faria isso no R?

Dentro da estruturura: tb1$col1 <- ....

Ex:

> TABELAS
>
> df1 <- data.frame(chave1 = c('A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
>                valores1 = c('alto', 'médio', 'alto', 'alto', 'baixo'))
>
> chave1 valores1
>   1      A     alto
>   2      A    médio
>   3      C     alto
>   4      D     alto
>   5      E    baixo
>
> df2 <- data.frame(chave2 = c('A', 'E', 'C'),
>                    valores2 = c('rico', 'poble', 'média'))
>
> chave2 valores2
>   1      A     rico
>   2      E    poble
>   3      C    média
>
> RESULTADO
>
> chave1 valores1
>   1      A     rico
>   2      A     rico
>   3      C     média
>   4      D     NA
>   5      E    poble

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como juntar vários datas frames em um só](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17347/como-juntar-v%c3%a1rios-datas-frames-em-um-s%c3%b3)

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é fornecer um exemplo reprodutível para que quem for responder possa simular o que você já tentou. Como você está acabando de chegar no SO vou fazer isso para você:

**CRIANDO UM EXEMPLO REPRODUTÍVEL**

```
df1 <- data.frame(chave1 = c('A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
              valores1 = c('alto', 'médio', 'alto', 'alto', 'baixo'))

  chave1 valores1
1      A     alto
2      A    médio
3      C     alto
4      D     alto
5      E    baixo

df2 <- data.frame(chave2 = c('A', 'E', 'C'),
                  valores2 = c('rico', 'poble', 'média'))

  chave2 valores2
1      A     rico
2      E    poble
3      C    média
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

A solução é o comando **merge**. Veja como funciona:

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = 'chave1', by.y = 'chave2')
```

o que resulta em

```
  chave1 valores1 valores2
1      A     alto     rico
2      A    médio     rico
3      C     alto    média
4      E    baixo    poble
```

**dplyr**

O `dplyr` é um pacote que permite fazer outros tipos de `joins`. Há ampla [documentação](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) sobre isso.

Comment: Opa vlw mas essa não seria a intenção, entendo que com o merge é possivel juntar as os dataframes e depois filtrar as colunas por um select, mas o que eu queria é algo que atualiza-se os valores de uma coluna pronta no R, e não precisar criar outro objeto.